# getting crash on null data with callback function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

Here is my code:

```
   func getProduct(productId: String, callback: @escaping (String) -> () ){

        Transport.sharedInstance.getProduct(productId: productId) { (data, err) in

            if let _ = err{

            }else{
                if let dt = data as? String{
                    let pro = Mapper<SubCategoryProducts>().map(JSONString: dt)
                    let com = ComboData()
                    com.price = pro?.Price ?? 0
                    com.type = pro?.type ?? ""
                    com.amount = pro?.quantity ?? ""

                    if (pro?.combodata == nil) {
                         pro?.combodata?.append(com)
                    } else if ((pro?.combodata?.contains(where: {$0.type == pro?.type})))! {

                    } else {

                        pro?.combodata?.append(com)
                    }
                    self.arrayForCombo.removeAll()
                    pro?.combodata?.forEach({ (com) in
                        let str = "\(com.amount) " + "\(com.type)" + "    -    " +  "₹ \(com.price)"
                        self.arrayForCombo.append(str)
                    })
                    callback(self.arrayForCombo[0])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting nil `pro?.combodata` so only I have checked wether I am getting nil value or not and then when it comes to callback it getting crash on here `callback(self.arrayForCombo[0])`. Because its not appending the values. I don't know why, but not able to achieve that. Any solution it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
 guard let pro = Mapper<SubCategoryProducts>().map(JSONString: dt) else { return }
 let com = ComboData()
 com.price = pro.Price ?? 0
 com.type = pro.type ?? ""
 com.amount = pro.quantity ?? ""

 if (pro.combodata == nil) {
   pro.combodata = [com]
 }
```

The problem is that when `combodata` of `pro` is nil than you are trying to append the object that means you are trying `nil.append()` while it should be `[ComboData].append()`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: It helps if "pro" is not nil - there is no checking for that particular case at all. Otherwise, "nil" has no property "combodata".

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I've updated for that condition too.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `forEach` is even stepped into.

At this point it can be that either `pro` or `pro.combodata` are nil and `forEach` is not called on nil collection.

Probably you're trying to access `[0]` index element after `self.arrayForCombo.removeAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

When the optional array is nil then calling append will do nothing, you need to initialize it first

```
if (pro?.combodata == nil) {
   pro?.combodata = []
   pro?.combodata?.append(com)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After executing `self.arrayForCombo.removeAll()` statement, `arrayForCombo` become empty. If your `pro?.combodata` is `nil` then `forEach` statement could not execute. So still your `arrayForCombo` is empty.
But in the `callBack` statement you forcefully try to access the first item of `arrayForCombo` whether it's empty or not. That's why it crushes when the array is empty.

You can safely by pass the cruhes like that:

```
if let firstItem = arrayForCombo.first {
    callback(firstItem)
}
```